# How to fix Gama Carousel's layout_gravity to center horizontal?

Tags: android, carousel, android-theme

I have a problem using Gama's carousel framework because everytime I run my android application, the carousel looks like its layout_gravity to center horizontal is not working, but if I remove the android:theme = "@style/AppTheme" on my manifest file, the carousel will be now fixed but that's not a good solution to my problem because it will also remove the theme of my application. What should I do to make this one solved.

This is my xml file for my carousel view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.digitalaria.gama.carousel.Carousel
        android:id="@+id/carousel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"/>    
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my xml file for a single item/picture on my carousel view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/itemImage" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"    
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

and finally, my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="bzguys.corporation.jaja"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="bzguys.corporation.jaja.CarouselViewActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.CAROUSELVIEWACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It may help you.

Add these lines in your java file. First declare the Carousel.

```
Carousel carousel;
```

Set gravity for the carousel.

```
carousel.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```